# trying to get Pandas to work by escaping the \

Tags: python, pandas, escaping

So I am trying to read an xlsx with Pandas, when I do I keep getting an error saying that the directory doesn't exist which it does.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\tmp\RVToolsvHost.xlsx')
```

This is the code. I thought the r meant raw so I didn't have to escape the \ but when I run it I get this error.

No such file or directory: 'C:\tmp\RVToolsvHost.xlsx'

so I try to write it like this...

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\tmp\\RVToolsvHost.xlsx')
```

I get this error

No such file or directory: 'C:\\tmp\\RVToolsvHost.xlsx'

I honestly have no idea what else to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `data = pd.read_excel('C:/tmp/RVToolsvHost.xlsx')`. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, either try `pd.read_excel('C:/tmp/RVToolsvHost.xlsx')` or `pd.read_excel("C:\\tmp\\RVToolsvHost.xlsx")` either **should** work

Comment: When I remove the r' and just have it like you have it, both of you I get this error...Invalid argument: 'C:\tmp\\RVToolsvInfo.xlsx'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not pandas, but lays within the filepath. I'd recommend to use `os.path.join()` to create a path-object off your String. This object then is even usable on mac, linux and windows (important because some deal it forward-slash "/" and some with backward-slash "\".

```py
import os  # os for operating system
import pandas as pd

PATH = "C:\tmp\RVToolsvHost.xlsx"
path_obj = os.path.join(PATH)

if path_obj.is_file():  # check whether it finds a file at given path
    print("path exists and is a file")

df = pd.read_excel(path_obj)
```